# Преобразование строки в дату

Tags: дата, php

Всем, привет! Уважаемое сообщество, подскажите пожалуйста, может уже кто-нить сталкивался с такой проблемой:

Получаю строки след. вида:

```
"Ноябрь 20 2012"
"Декабрь 19 2012"
"Сентябрь 12 2012"
"Июнь 5 2012"
"Август 2 2012"
```

Необходимо представить эти строки в след. формате:

```
11.20.2012
12.19.2012
09.12.2012
06.05.2012
08.02.2012
```

Проблемы конечно нету получить год и число, а вот как быть с месяцем.

Нашел я функцию которая парсит дату, но понятное дело с месяцем облом:

```
$date = "Ноябрь 20 2012";
print_r(date_parse_from_format("F j Y", $date));
```

Помогите пожалуйста советом, как быть с месяцем!

В ДОПОЛНЕНИИ к ответу [[@Равнодушный](/users/8603/%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%88%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9)](/users/8603/%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%88%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9):

```
function newFormatDate($date) {
    $date = str_replace(
                array('Январь', 'Фервраль', 'Март', 'Апрель', 'Май', 'Июнь', 'Июль', 'Август', 'Сентябрь', 'Октябрь', 'Ноябрь', 'Декабрь'),
                array('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'),
                $date);
    return date("d.m.Y", strtotime($date));
}

foreach($html->find('div.narrow_column div div.postdate') as $element) {
    $dateNews = $element->innertext;
    $date = $dateNews;
    $date = newFormatDate($dateNews);
    $array_dateNews[] = $date;
}
```

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает, что нужно вручную проверять, какой месяц.

Comment: дык мне вот тоже подсказывает, но неужели... :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Не вижу ничего сложного с конвертацией, функция пишется за минуту. Например, такой вариант:

```
function newFormatDate($date) {
    $date = str_replace(array('Январь', 'Фервраль', 'Март', 'Апрель', 'Май', 'Июнь', 'Июль', 'Август', 'Сентябрь', 'Октябрь', 'Ноябрь', 'Декабрь'),
                        array('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'),
                        $date);
return date("d.m.Y", strtotime($date));
}

$date = 'Ноябрь 20 2012';
echo newFormatDate($date);

/*Результат
20.11.2012
*/
```

Comment: Благодарствую ! :)

Comment: @Равнодушный подскажите пожалуйста, при выполнении кода (дополнил вопрос), получается результат 01.01.1970

Comment: 1) код не работает с датами до 1902 года... 2) я мог неправильно написать англоязычное название месяца... 3) Дата может приходить в значении 0.

Приведите пример входной даты, с которой функция не справляется.

Comment: @Равнодушный а как сменить кодировку у массива:

array("Январь", "Февраль", "Март", "Апрель", "Май", "Июнь", "Июль", "Август", "Сентябрь", "Октябрь", "Ноябрь", "Декабрь");

iconv( "UTF-8", "windows-1251", $searchPattern); - не работает
 :((((

Comment: ? зачем? во что вам надо сменить? сохраните файл через notepad++ в ANSI для win1251 либо в UTF8 для UTF8 соответственно. все букаффки сохранятся именно в выбранной кодировке же :)

Comment: К комментарию @thunder добавить нечего...)

Comment: Да уж братцы спасибо, такого тупняка от себя не ожидал )))