# Неверно отображается дата

Tags: дата, php

Всем привет! Уважаемое сообщество, прошу вашей помощи, в продолжении [вот этой темы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/165861/php-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83).

При выполнении вот такой конструкции, получается результат **01.01.1970**

```
function newFormatDate($date) {
    $date = str_replace(
                array('Январь', 'Фервраль', 'Март', 'Апрель', 'Май', 'Июнь', 'Июль', 'Август', 'Сентябрь', 'Октябрь', 'Ноябрь', 'Декабрь'),
                array('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'),
                $date);
    return date("d.m.Y", strtotime($date));
}

foreach($html->find('div.narrow_column div div.postdate') as $element) {
    $dateNews = $element->innertext;
    $date = $dateNews;
    $date = newFormatDate($dateNews);
    $array_dateNews[] = $date;
}
```

Результат **echo $dateNews;** если поможет:

```
Ноябрь 21st, 2012 
Ноябрь 20 2012 
Ноябрь 19 2012 
Ноябрь 16 2012
и т.д.
```

Comment: чота комменты перестали добавляться. тут не массив надо менять, а кодировку самого файла. я обычно это все в notepad++ делаю, какую выбрал  в такой все и сохранилось, в том числе и русские буквы. и вообще лучше забыть про win1251 и делать все на UTF8...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А с чего она верно должна отображаться?? Проверьте сначала как у вас выводится `$date`

Прочитайте в [каком формате](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_chapter/Date-input-formats.html#SEC121) должен быть первый аргумент `strtotime()`

зыж все работает на utf8. не бойтесь выводить промежуточные значения чтобы понимать что происходит. посмотрике как у меня это сделано :) все же просто :)

```
function newFormatDate($date) {
$date = str_replace(array('Январь', 'Фервраль', 'Март', 'Апрель', 'Май', 'Июнь', 'Июль', 'Август', 'Сентябрь', 'Октябрь', 'Ноябрь', 'Декабрь'),
                    array('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'),
                    $date);
                    echo "$date<br/>";
$dt = strtotime($date);
return date("d.m.Y", $dt);
}

foreach($html->find('div.narrow_column div div.postdate') as $element) {
    $dateNews = $element->innertext;
//      $dateNews = iconv( "UTF-8", "windows-1251", $dateNews);     
    echo "$dateNews<br/>";

    $dateNews = preg_replace('/^(.*?\s)(.*?\s.*?,\s.*?\s)(.*?\s.*?)$/', '$2', $dateNews);
//      $dateNews = preg_replace('/^(.*?\s)(\d{1,2})(st,|th,)(\s\d{4})/', '$2$1$4', $dateNews);
//      $dateNews = date_parse_from_format("d.m.Y", $dateNews);
    echo "$dateNews<br/>";

//      print_r($dateNews['day']);
    echo newFormatDate($dateNews);
```

Comment: ну вот и замечательно)

Comment: @thunder что-то я поторопился с ответом, не сразу заметил, что дата у меня все равно 01.01.1970, даже после подгона под GNU, что самое интересное, пример из прошлой темы работает без подгона под GNU

Comment: ой чтото [у вас](http://w.thunders.spb.ru/test5.php) с настройками :)

Comment: еще не понял вот это :)))))

    $date = $dateNews;
    $date = newFormatDate($dateNews);

Comment: вот сюда http://codepad.org/NaC3bvrS выложил полный кусок кода, только библиотеку SimpleHTMLDOM надо подключить, правда я уже там накрутил чего попало

Comment: Лучше бы показали кусок html, который парсите...)

Comment: `setlocale` может не работать очень легко. это раз)
второе и самое главное! воопервых все должно работать на ОДНОЙ кодировке, у меня заработало на utf-8 когда я и файл в utf-8 преобразовал и сделал вот так ()

Comment: Кстати, про кодировку - очень дельная мысль... Так что лучше не "да неее вряд ли", а проверить...)

Comment: КОРОЧЕ ВСЕ ПОНЯТНО НАРОД! :))) вот массив который в сравнение идет 

Array ( [0] => РЇРЅРІР°СЂСЊ [1] => Р¤РµРІСЂР°Р»СЊ [2] => РњР°СЂС‚ [3] => РђРїСЂРµР»СЊ [4] => РњР°Р№ [5] => РСЋРЅСЊ [6] => РСЋР»СЊ [7] => РђРІРіСѓСЃС‚ [8] => РЎРµРЅС‚СЏР±СЂСЊ [9] => РћРєС‚СЏР±СЂСЊ [10] => РќРѕСЏР±СЂСЊ [11] => Р”РµРєР°Р±СЂСЊ ) Ноябрь 21 2012 РћРїСѓР±Р»РёРєРѕРІР°РЅРѕ РќРѕСЏР±СЂСЊ 20th, 2012 РђРІС‚РѕСЂ РђРЅР°СЃС‚Р°СЃРёСЏ


Это блин наши месяцы

Comment: @thunder а как сменить кодировку у массива?